# HTML5 FileUpload delayed

Tags: html, file-upload, form-data

I've an html form with an add button. On button click the data form are appended as table row to a table below the form.
When the user is ready he could push a save button, all table rows are read and the data added to a json object, to post everything to the back-end.
Everything works fine.
Now I would like to add a file to the form. So it should be temporally saved (maybe just the ref?) paired to the own table row, and when the save button will be pushed everything have to be posted to the back-end. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You'd need to store the file data in memory (or base64 encoded to the HTML).

Comment: feel free to write an answer, I'll accept it.